# Where is autofill in stored?

Tags: firefox, cookies

When I changed the filename of the firefox cookies file I noticed that when I went to facebook I now did not instantly get on my account as I normaly do. I expected this to happen. However when I came to the login page of facebook I saw that my username and password field were already filled in.

I expected that this would also be in the cookie file I renamed.
So how does my browser still know this information and where is it stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cookies won't remove the passwords and bookmarks. The passwords and bookmarks info are saved in a folder named profile. It is a folder which is independent of firefox so that even if you remove firefox your info will not be lost. In ubuntu it can be found at `~/.mozilla/firefox.` [Read this for more info](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)